# Change second dropdown item on selection of first dropdown item

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have two Drop down list.

First drop down is list of months and second is for days.

I want when I select month from first drop down, items of second dropdown change according to selection of first dropdown.

For Example- if I select January from first dropdown, second drop down list become 1 to 31. On selction of february, second drop down list become 1 to 29.

I am trying with this code but not working-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getDays(dropdownMonth.SelectedValue);

    }

public void getDays(string selectedMonth)
    {
        int i = 0;
         dropdownDays.Items.Clear();
        switch (selectedMonth)
        {
            case "January":
                i = 31;
                break;
            case "February":
                i = 29;
                break;
            case "March":
                i = 31;
                break;
            case "April":
                i = 30;
                break;
            case "May":
                i = 31;
                break;
            case "June":
                i = 30;
                break;
            case "July":
                i = 31;
                break;
            case "August":
                i = 31;
                break;
            case "September":
                i = 30;
                break;
            case "October":
                i = 31;
                break;
            case "November":
                i = 30;
                break;
            case "December":
                i = 31;
                break;
        }

        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            dropdownDays.Items.Add(j.ToString());
        }
        int Month = DateTime.ParseExact(Convert.ToString(dropdownMonth.SelectedValue), "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month;
        int day = Convert.ToInt32(dropdownDays.SelectedValue);
        int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
        DateTime date = new DateTime(year, Month, day);
        lblEndDateValue.Text = String.Format("{0:dd MMMM}", date.AddDays(-1));
```

if i remove `dropdownmonth.items.clear();` from my code then it works but then it adds new days list to previous list on this dropdown.

Comment: Is it not submitting (doing nothing) or is it updating the days, but not correct?

Comment: it's showing correct dates on selection of month but on selection, it's not selected. it become from starting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Selected index changed event for first dropdownlist and set autopostback=true    for first dropdown

```
   protected void dropdownMonth_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       getDays(dropdownMonth.SelectedValue);
   }
```

set AutoPostBack="true" for dropdownDays also,

```
  protected void dropdownDays_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LabelDays.Text = dropdownDays.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Comment: set AutoPostBack="true" only for dropdownMonth

Comment: Remove  getDays(dropdownMonth.SelectedValue); from the pageload

Comment: try this it will work

Comment: it's working but i also want to show that date and month immediate on a label, it's not changing on label

Comment: Its working for me try this

Comment: what will be on page load ?

Comment: Remove all the code from page load sure it will work

Comment: it's showing last date of selected month on labeldays.text, not showing selected date from dropdowndays

Comment: Use the updated code keep the old code itself additional add this code its working fine for me

Comment: it's not working. not doing anything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52724/discussion-between-karthikmanoharan-and-azhar-shahid)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..You must bind your code inside `!ispostback`..Otherwise the on each postback the value get reset..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostback)
   {
       //getDays(dropdownMonth.SelectedValue);
   }
}
```

You can call your function in `selectedidexchanged` event of  month dropdown and set `Autopostback=true` for the dropdown..I don't think you must call it on pageload..

```
 protected void dropdownMonth_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       getDays(dropdownMonth.SelectedValue);
   }
```

Comment: not changing immediate on selection.

Comment: It should be `!IsPostback` as this won't compile

Comment: yes i tried it, not working immediate

Comment: @AzharShahid  I didn't get you friend,Can you please elaborate..Where is the problem and where are you binding the month dropdown?

Comment: @geedubb typo error friend,thanks for your help..

Comment: @AzharShahid Update answer please try,regards..

Comment: it's working but i also want to show that date and month immediate on a label, it's not changing on label

Comment: Can you please post the code where you setting the label text?]

Comment: edited my code in question